# Initializing Select value dynamically in angular2

Tags: angular

I am setting value of select option in a loop . Have a look at the code

```
<div *ngFor="let sport of sport_data;" class="row">
  <select [(ngModel)]="sports.value" class="form-control">
      <option value="football">Sports</option>
      <option value="cricket">Cricket</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here sport_data is the array of list of sports . Its not working fine . Is their any other way to set default value of select element?

Answer (score 1):

Should the select have a binding to the "sport" variable of the *ngFor? In that case it seems that you have a typo, as you bind the ngModel to "sports" and not "sport". The code should look like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let sport of sport_data;" class="row">
  <select [(ngModel)]="sport.value" class="form-control">
      <option value="football">Sports</option>
      <option value="cricket">Cricket</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

As you asked for it, a different approach could be to use the (change) event on the select to set the value and the [selected] binding for the option to be selected.

Comment: Here I am using ngmodel to set default value and sport.value returns value like football and cricket . Even after correcting my typo error its not working .

Comment: @MOHIT I made a small plunkr with your code, see [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/BTbsjQL1yBlOFa58OKEF?p=preview). Is this what you want to achieve? I.e. multiple selection boxes for each field of your sport_data?

Comment: Yes thats what i was trying to achieve . Thanks